# How to get index of the row click of the gridview in the asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

Hi i have a gridview generated from the data table from the data base using the stored procedure. In the item template of the grid view i have 3 columns first column is of radio button , second is the  Message_Number and third one is the Messag_Title. when user clicks other radio button i need to get the row id of the selected radio button . How can do that can any one guide me in this.

Comment: please provide what you've tried.

Comment: Please check the link:https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/391447/Get-Row-Index-on-click-of-Radio-Button-in-GridView

Comment: Provide the `.aspx` and `.cs` code, so it can be modified to fulfil your requirement.